# binary operator % cannot be applied to operands of type UInt32 and int

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
var Y: Int = 0
Y = arc4random() % 5
```

I am getting the error

> "binary operator % cannot be applied to operands of type UInt32 and
>   int". How can I fix my syntax

Answer (score 3):

Use following

```
var Y: Int = 0
Y = Int( arc4random() % 5 )
```

Comment: It does not compile.

Comment: It does for me. Just verified in playground

Comment: @Brduca It works fine for me, but without compiling because I can't due to other error I am working on.

Comment: I'll get back to you guys

Comment: Getting the same problem on ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + X, ball.center.y + Y) "binary operator + cannot be applied to operands of type CGfloat int". I tried fixing it with them same method but that didn't work

Comment: In this case you'll have to do this way ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + CGFloat ( X ), ball.center.y + CGFloat( Y ) )

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

var Y: UInt32 = 0
Y = arc4random() % 5
```

The % function returns an UInt32.

From Apple docs:

```
/// Divide `lhs` and `rhs`, returning the remainder and trapping in case of
/// arithmetic overflow (except in -Ounchecked builds).
@warn_unused_result
public func %<T : _IntegerArithmeticType>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T

public func %(lhs: Int64, rhs: Int64) -> Int64

public func %(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8

public func %(lhs: UInt64, rhs: UInt64) -> UInt64

public func %(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32

public func %(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32

public func %(lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16) -> Int16

public func %(lhs: UInt16, rhs: UInt16) -> UInt16

public func %(lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8) -> UInt8

public func %=(inout lhs: Float, rhs: Float)

public func %=(inout lhs: Double, rhs: Double)

public func %=(inout lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80)
```

this are the overloads of %, since the only method that allows an UInt32 as first parameter the response type is an UInt32. 
You can solve the problem by casting the result to an Int or changing the var Y to UInt32.

Comment: It's not related to `%`: what happens is that *arc4random* returns an UInt32, but Swift is good at inferring types so it decides that in this situation `5` is *also* an UInt32 and not just an Int, so the types "magically" match.

Comment: @EricD. following apple docs "public func %(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32". In this case the return type of % is an UInt32.

Comment: It's an overloaded operator, it uses UInt32 here *because* this is the inferred type, as I explained. Try using `%` with two Ints an you'll understand what happens...

Comment: Yes, I was wrong when i said that it does not compile both ways works.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is fine, the semantics is wrong.

Swift doesn't like random type conversions. You've got a very clear error message: You can't do UInt32 % int. So you need to change one of the operands, either UInt32 % UInt32 or int % int (if that's what your error message said).

Of course after that the assignment will fail, because you can't assign UInt32 to Int. As I said, Swift doesn't like random type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

This one also works:

```
var Y: Int = 0
Y = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `%` operation, you should rather use the modern `arc4random_uniform` function:

```
let y = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
```